# Debug OFBiz in Netbeans

Tags: java, debugging, netbeans, ofbiz

I want to debug ofbiz (apache Open For Business project) in netbeans.
When i mark a line as breakpoint, i get this error:

> Not able to submit breakpoint LineBreakpoint X.java : 58, reason: No source root found for URL ...

help me.
Thanks.